Get Username for current session on Remote Desktop Services (RDS) from System account?
I'm trying to get the username of the current session from a system account.  I've read this, but no solution works reliably:
Finding current logged on user(s) while running as SYSTEM (no environment variables)

Getting the user running explorer.exe doesn't work, since there may be multiple explorer.exe processes running on an RDS session and you can't decipher which is the current session.
The chevron (denoting current session?) returned by Quser, Query Session etc is unreliable (sometimes the chevron was next to the wrong "Active" user)
Win32_Computersystem doesn't work

I'm running out of ideas!  Any help appreciated!
When i say "current session", there could be multiple active user sessions logged in on RDS concurrently:
UserA (Active)
UserB (Active)
UserC (Active)
But if I'm UserB and am currently logged in when my PowerShell script runs as a SYSTEM account, I want it to return UserB.  Not NT Authority\SYSTEM.  Not UserA and not UserC.
UPDATE
Here is an example of what a typical server session might look like:

You can see there are multiple "Active" sessions - some connected by RDP, others ICA.  I need to be able to decipher which user is the current user I am logged in as (from a SYSTEM account)

Can you clarify what you mean by "current session"? If you're running as system then the username is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

The current "interactive" desktop session.  In other words, there could be many "active" sessions running concurrently on RDS.  But I want the username of the interactive session that is logged in when my PowerShell script runs as a SYSTEM account.  Hope that makes sense.

I've included an image above.  Your code did return the console session of 1, which has no associated username.  I'm trying to find out who I am currently logged in as from a SYSTEM account.  In the above example, it could be any one of the "Active" ICA/RDP session names.

Assuming that "current session" means the active console session.
In that case you can retrieve the session id by calling WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId.

Retrieves the session identifier of the console session. The console session is the session that is currently attached to the physical console

Once you have the sessionid you can pass that to WTSQuerySessionInformation with WTSInfoClass WTSUserName.
Example:
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WTS {
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
        IntPtr hServer, 
        uint SessionId, 
        WTS_INFO_CLASS WTSInfoClass, 
        out IntPtr ppBuffer, 
        out uint pBytesReturned);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    public static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);

    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS {
        WTSInitialProgram = 0,
        WTSApplicationName = 1,
        WTSWorkingDirectory = 2,
        WTSSessionId = 4,
        WTSUserName = 5,
        WTSWinStationName = 6,
        WTSDomainName = 7,
        WTSConnectState = 8,
        WTSClientBuildNumber = 9,
        WTSClientName = 10,
        WTSClientDirectory = 11,
        WTSClientProductId = 12,
        WTSClientHardwareId = 13,
        WTSClientAddress = 14,
        WTSClientDisplay = 15,
        WTSClientProtocolType = 16,
        WTSIdleTime = 17,
        WTSLogonTime = 18,
        WTSIncomingBytes = 19,
        WTSOutgoingBytes = 20,
        WTSIncomingFrames = 21,
        WTSOutgoingFrames = 22,
        WTSClientInfo = 23,
        WTSSessionInfo = 24,
        WTSSessionInfoEx = 25,
        WTSConfigInfo = 26,
        WTSValidationInfo = 27,
        WTSSessionAddressV4 = 28,
        WTSIsRemoteSession = 29
    }

    public static string GetUsername(uint sessionId) {
        IntPtr buffer;
        uint bytesReturned;
        string userName = "Unknown";

        if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out buffer, out bytesReturned) && bytesReturned > 1) {
            userName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
            WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
"@ -Namespace "Win32" -UsingNamespace "System.Runtime.InteropServices"

# Get the active console session ID
$sessionId = [Win32.WTS]::WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
if ($sessionId -eq 0xFFFFFFFF) {
    Write-Host "No active session."
} else {
    # Get the username associated with this session
    $username = [Win32.WTS]::GetUsername($sessionId)
    Write-Host "Username: $username"
}

Updated answer after more clarification as you seem to want to know the username of the sessionid that your .exe runs in (regardsless of the account associated with your process):
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class WTS {
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(
        IntPtr hServer, 
        uint SessionId, 
        WTS_INFO_CLASS WTSInfoClass, 
        out IntPtr ppBuffer, 
        out uint pBytesReturned);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    public static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);

    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS {
        WTSInitialProgram = 0,
        WTSApplicationName = 1,
        WTSWorkingDirectory = 2,
        WTSSessionId = 4,
        WTSUserName = 5,
        WTSWinStationName = 6,
        WTSDomainName = 7,
        WTSConnectState = 8,
        WTSClientBuildNumber = 9,
        WTSClientName = 10,
        WTSClientDirectory = 11,
        WTSClientProductId = 12,
        WTSClientHardwareId = 13,
        WTSClientAddress = 14,
        WTSClientDisplay = 15,
        WTSClientProtocolType = 16,
        WTSIdleTime = 17,
        WTSLogonTime = 18,
        WTSIncomingBytes = 19,
        WTSOutgoingBytes = 20,
        WTSIncomingFrames = 21,
        WTSOutgoingFrames = 22,
        WTSClientInfo = 23,
        WTSSessionInfo = 24,
        WTSSessionInfoEx = 25,
        WTSConfigInfo = 26,
        WTSValidationInfo = 27,
        WTSSessionAddressV4 = 28,
        WTSIsRemoteSession = 29
    }

    public static string GetUsername(uint sessionId) {
        IntPtr buffer;
        uint bytesReturned;
        string userName = "Unknown";

        if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out buffer, out bytesReturned) && bytesReturned > 1) {
            userName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
            WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
"@

# define WTS_CURRENT_SESSION
[uint32]$WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = [uint32]::MaxValue

# get username for "current" session:
[WTS]::GetUsername($WTS_CURRENT_SESSION)



Thanks.  I had to remove "-Namespace "Win32" -UsingNamespace "System.Runtime.InteropServices"" from AddType, and declare "namespace Win32 {}" within the code instead.  But even when I run it as the logged in user, it successfully returns a session ID but the username is always "unknown".

Added a screenshot above which explains why console username is blank....

As you can see from your own screenshot, there is no user currently logged on to the console session (else it would be active instead of connected).

If you want to know the username of the sessionid which is associated with your (system process) you can pass WTS_CURRENT_SESSION. In C, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION is defined as (DWORD)-1 so in PowerShell you can use [uint32]$WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = [uint32]::MaxValue

Thanks for that.  Weirdly, it works when i run a PowerShell console as SYSTEM (using psexec -i -s).  But when I run it as a scheduled task as the SYSTEM account (powershell.exe -file xxx.ps1) it comes back as unknown?

when you run it as a scheduled task it will be running in the services session (session 0) which of course has no attached user. Read/refresh docs on service isolation, this might be good starting point: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/ba-p/372473

To get only interactive logon sessions, query for the Win32_LogonSession class and filter on LogonType - grab the associated Win32_Account instances to identify the owning user account:
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogonSession -Filter "LogonType = 2" |Get-CimAssociatedInstance -ResultClassName Win32_Account |Sort-Object Caption -Unique


Get-CimAssociatedInstance doesn't return anything.  But how would I know which logon session is this current session?  And not somebody elses?

You can check in the registry : the current logged on user has a key "Volatile Environment" in HKCU
$CurrentUser = Get-ChildItem Registry::\HKEY_USERS  | Where-Object { Test-Path "$($_.pspath)\Volatile Environment" } | ForEach-Object { (Get-ItemProperty "$($_.pspath)\Volatile Environment").USERNAME }
if ($CurrentUser -eq $null) {Write-Warning "No user connected"}
Else {Write-Host "Logged on user is $CurrentUser"}


Thought about that. But how do you know which HKCU to check? Remember I'm sunning asleep SYSTEM account, so the HKCU will be for the SYSTEM account. So I'd need to enumerate HKU and pick one....the current one....somehow?

This script enumerate HKU and pick the one that  has a key "Volatile Environment"

In RDS, there are multiple populated Volatile keys....
